# Check if input is float else stop

Tags: c

```
scanf("%f", &num);
```

I have to check if thats a valid float variable and stop executing if it has symbols like `@` or `!` or `%` etc..

Suggestions?

Comment: The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for `scanf` explains that its return value indicates the number of values it matched.  In your case, this would be 1 if `num` has been set to a valid `float`

Comment: There is no need to write "In C" in your title, the tag already did that.

Comment: Are you looking for a valid float on a line by itself? Because `scanf` will succeed in retrieving a float if it finds one but even if there's "stuff" after it. For example, `scanf("%f", &num)` will return `1` (number of floats read) from an input such as `3.2@#$$%`, putting a value of `3.2` into `num`. It just stops reading when it hits the `@`. If you need to scan past the "stuff" to get to the next float, you'll need a mechanism for that since `scanf("%f"...)` will just sit there, stuck at the `@` on subsequent calls, returning `0`, unless you do something else.

Comment: You should give us examples of what inputs will be accepted and rejected, if any. Or generally what you want your program to do given a certain bunch of inputs. (Does "stop executing" mean your program should exit with an error message? Or that `scanf()` should stop scanning?) Neither `scanf()` nor `strtol()` do "validation", that is they will accept any string that starts with a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` is not your friend, here.  Even if you check the result to
ensure that you read one whole argument successfully, that doesn't
really guarantee that the input is valid in a meaningful sense.

Given input like:

```
1!!!1!oneone!
```

the `%f` parsing will stop (but succeed) after reading the first `1`,
and leave the read pointer at the following `!`.  This may not be what
you consider "valid input".

In that case, try:

```
if (scanf("%f%c", &f, &c) == 2 && isspace(c))
    /* success */
```

This will, however, accept things like:

```
1 oneoneonespace!bang
```

If anything on the same line is to be considered garbage, then it gets
difficult, because `scanf` doesn't distinguish between spaces and
newlines.  Perhaps try something like this:

```
char buffer[1024];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
{
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%f %c", &f, &c) == 1)
        /* success */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the return value from `scanf()`. It will return the number of successfully scanned inputs - in your case it should be `1`. If it is not equal to one, it could be -1 which means "end of file" or 0, which means "input wasn't valid".

Answer (score 2):

Using the %f specifier in scanf won't scan anything else, if no float is specified, nothing will be read. You should check the return value of scanf.

There are a few defined return values:

```
EOF = -1
invalid input = 0
valid = >0
```

Answer (score 1):

Read your input as text, then convert it with the `strtod` library function; that allows you to check if the input contains any invalid characters:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
char buf=[81];
double result = 0.0;
...
if ( fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin ) != NULL )
{
  char *chk;
  double tmp = strtod( buf, &chk );
  if ( isspace( *chk ) || *chk == 0 )
    result = tmp;
  else
    fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid floating-point number\n", buf );
}
```

After the call to `strtod`, the variable `chk` will point to the first character in the string that is not part of a valid floating-point constant.  If this character is whitespace or 0, then you're good; otherwise you have bad input.

The advantage to this method over `scanf` is that if your input starts with just one valid character (such as `"1blkjhsdf"`), it will convert and assign the `"1"` and return a 1, indicating a successful conversion, even though you'd probably want to reject that input.  It also consumes the entire input string (provided the input buffer is large enough), so it doesn't leave any garbage in the input stream to foul up the next read.

`scanf` is a good tool to use when you *know* your input is well-formed; otherwise, better to use the method above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check for both of your conditions in `scanf`. I would suggest reading whole input into a string, look for special characters. Once this test passes, try re-processing it into a string via [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).
To search for special characters there is a [`strpbrk`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) defined in `string.h`

```
char* specials = "%@!";
char* buffer[SOME_SIZE];
double value;
int err;

scanf("%s", buffer);
if( strpbrk(buffer, specials) ) return SPECIAL_FOUND;
err = sscanf(buffer, "%f", &value);
if(err <= 0) return NOT_VALID_INPUT; //NOTE: there should probably be not EOF case

// process your value
```

Note: I did not check the code it's a rough idea to play with.

Comment: `strtof()` is better still as it tells where it stopped parsing and you can use it to check for `\0`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I'll yoink that fact for the ideone sample I gave in lulyon's answer, I was using strlen() originally.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the return value from `scanf()`. If you look at [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) :

> **Return value**
>
> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. **This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file**.

So something like :

```
if ( scanf( "%f", &num ) <= 0 )
{
    // Stop the execution
}
// Continue
```

will do what you want.