# How to Make this Code Work (isdigit)

Tags: c, numbers

So, I'm creating a program that calculates the area of a triangle, and I need it to tell the user if he typed a letter or a negative number, in order, I created the code:
I need to use isdigit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main () {
    float a, b, c;
    float s=0, ar1=0, ar2=0;
    printf("Inform the value of side A.");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%f",&a);
    while(a<=0||isdigit((int)a)){
        printf("Invalid value.");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%f",&a);
    }printf("Inform the value of side B.");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    while(b<=0||isdigit((int)a)){
        printf("Invalid value.");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%f",&b);
    }printf("Inform the value of side C.");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%f",&c);
    while(c<=0||isdigit((int)a)){
        printf("Invalid value.");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%f",&c);}
         s=((a+b+c)/2);
        ar1=(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
        ar2=pow(ar1,0.5);
   printf("The semiperimeter is %f",s);
   printf("The area of the triangle is%f",ar2);
   system ("pause");
   return 1;
}
```

But, when I compile/run it, and type "x", or "blabla" when I was supposed to type a number, nothing happens, and the program doesn't warn me, what should I do?

Comment: Also, I'm a beginner, so I don't know many functions in C

Comment: Remove all those `fflush(stdin)` . It is UB on many implementations.

Comment: What's UB? And I removed it, nothing happened

Comment: scanf is probably not the right tool for your requirements. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210406/check-if-input-is-float-else-stop) which solves the same problem and an explanation for why scanf will not do the right thing for you.

Comment: @RafaelVignoli , UB means Undefined Behavior. Basically, it means that anything can happen. Google it and you'll see what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using `fflush` on `stdin` is Undefined Behavior as per the C11 standard, although it is well defined on some implementations.

Secondly, you can't use simply use `isdigit` that way. Once `%f` sees invalid data such as characters, the `scanf` terminates and the corresponding argument is left untouched. Also, using `isdigit` on an uninitialized variable leads to Undefined Behavior.

What you can do is check the return value of `scanf`. All the three `scanf`s in your code returns 1 if successful.

---

**Fixed Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h> //Unused header


void flushstdin() //Removes all characters from stdin
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); //Scan and discard everything until a newline character or EOF
}

int main () {

    float a, b, c;
    float s=0, ar1=0, ar2=0;

    printf("Inform the value of side A\n");
    //fflush(stdin); Avoid this to make your code portable
    while(scanf("%f",&a) != 1 || a <= 0){
        printf("Invalid value\n");
        flushstdin(); //Alternative way to flush stdin
    }

    printf("Inform the value of side B\n");
    //fflush(stdin);
    while(scanf("%f",&b) != 1 || b <= 0){
        printf("Invalid value\n");
        flushstdin(); //Alternative way to flush stdin
    }

    printf("Inform the value of side C\n");
    //fflush(stdin);
    while(scanf("%f",&c) != 1 || c <= 0){
        printf("Invalid value\n");
        flushstdin(); //Alternative way to flush stdin
    }

    s=((a+b+c)/2);
    ar1=(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
    ar2=pow(ar1,0.5);

    printf("The semiperimeter is %f\n", s);
    printf("The area of the triangle is %f\n", ar2);
    system ("pause");
    return 0; // 0 is usually returned for successful termination
}
```

Also, it is better to add newline characters at the end of the strings in `printf` as seen in the above program. They

- Improve readability
- Flushes the stdout

Comment: Thank you SO SO SO SO much!

Comment: Hmm but now, when I calculate the area, it always says: "The area of the triangle is -1.#IND00 What does that mean? @Cool Guy

Comment: No idea. What is your input?

Comment: "Inform the value of side A"
2
"Inform the value of side B"
2
"Inform the value of side C"
5
The semiperimeter is 4.5000000
The area of the triangle is -1.#IND00
@Cool Guy

Comment: @RafaelVignoli , Because you **cannot** construct a triangle with length of sides 2,2,5

Comment: @RafaelVignoli Output the value of `ar1`, too, and think about when the square root is defined.