# How to make min,max of Float array

Tags: c

This is my code, can somebody fix it
I need array of 5 float numbers and after it minimum and maximum

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define MAX_SIZE 100
int main()
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE],i;
    float max, min,size=5;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr [i]);
    }
    max = arr[0];
    min = arr[0];
    for(i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum element = %0.2f\n", max);
    printf("Minimum element = %0.2f", min);
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe u can help me, idk

Comment: Help you with what ? Is there a problem ?

Comment: @John3136 program is not working

Comment: Your array and input are for `int` not `float`.

Comment: @WeatherVane when i'm making it float, compilator says: Array subscript is not an integer

Comment: @WeatherVane ok, when i'm making float arr[MAX_SIZE]; Compilator says: Array subscript is not an integer. When int arr[MAX_SIZE] i have problem with output it's always Maximum element = 1573705600.00
Minimum element = 5.00

Comment: My guess is that you actually put `float arr[MAX_SIZE], i;` instead of `float arr[MAX_SIZE]; int i;`

Comment: @WeatherVane ok i change it, but output still give wrong answers: 5.25 2.53 3.64 4.64 5.515
Maximum element = 0.00
Minimum element = -2.21

Comment: Follow the compiler warnings.

Comment: I suppose you have corrected the type of `arr[]` as `float arr[MAX_SIZE]` in the declaration. Did you modify `scanf("%d", &arr [i]);` to `scanf("%f", &arr[i]);` too? As @Vladyslav comments, the compiler should warn about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to refactor your scanf for unwanted values [Check how to scanf a float with no input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210406/check-if-input-is-float-else-stop)

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100
int main()
{
  float arr[MAX_SIZE];
  int i;
  float max, min,size=5;
  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
      scanf("%f", &arr [i]);
  }
  max = arr[0];
  min = arr[0];
  for(i=1; i<size; i++)
  {
      if(arr[i] > max)
      {
          max = arr[i];
      }
      if(arr[i] < min)
      {
          min = arr[i];
      }
  }
  printf("Maximum element = %0.2f\n", max);
  printf("Minimum element = %0.2f", min);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is a better solution using your defined Global MAX_SIZE rather then having 100 float array , you will have enough and save some memory space . Initialize your float array value so you don't pick up memory values and try to make sure you control the input to to cause you program to have bugs read above article

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define MAX_SIZE 5
int main()
{
    float arr[MAX_SIZE] ;
    int i;
    float max, min;
    for(i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &arr [i]);
    }
    max = arr[0];
    min = arr[0];
    for(i=1; i<MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum element = %0.2f\n", max);
    printf("Minimum element = %0.2f", min);
    return 0;
}
```